# display:table, rows not level

Tags: css, tablelayout

I was trying to display my form using the table layout. The rest button is not level with the submit button and I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

CSS:

```
body
{
    display:table
}

col1,col2
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhqAX/

Comment: Your CSS says `#login col1`, but there is nothing with `id="login"` in your HTML, so the second CSS rule is never triggered for `col1`, only for `col2`. If at all; some browsers refuse to deal with invalid HTML elements and don't apply the css to them.

Comment: There is, I just pasted the code incorrectly in the fiddle - updates

Comment: Anyway, you might be better off simulating a real table. Including table rows!

Comment: @MrLister I don't use the table tag because table tags are not for layout, they're to tabulate data.

Comment: I did say "simulate". But do you really think using non-existent elements is better than using real HTML?

Comment: @Mr Lister: the reason is "semantic web". We choose tags based on `their meanings`, not by presentation. In this case, table tag is not suitable because table tag is for tabular data, not for layout. Presentation should be Css roles. I forgot about that

Comment: @KhanhTO You are wrong. We can't choose our own element names. We must select from the elements that are available to us. Otherwise, the question if it's semantic HTML or not won't matter - it won't even be HTML. Besides, like I said, some browsers refuse to style non-HTML elements.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I mean we should use `div` or `section` to layout (depending on the meaning), because table is for tabular data, not for layout. I agree with you that we should not use col1, col2 (not standard html tags)

Comment: @KhanhTO I guess I thought 'possible' meant 'allowed'. I guess using custom tags isn't technically allowed. I will eliminate these

Comment: @Neeta: the problem when you use non-standard tags is these tags are only understood by you (your app). Others on the internet don't know what they mean (for example: search engine bots).

Comment: @Neeta: only use custom tags when these tags are **very specific to your application**. Another example of non-standard is http status code, if the server returns 401 (unauthorized), we all know what it means. But if you devise your own status (600 for unauthorized), only your app knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css:

```
body
{
    display:table
}
div.row
{
    display:table-row;
}
div.cell
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
      <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The Username must be at least 5 characters long." data-val-length-max="10" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>   
<div class="row">   
  <div class="cell">  
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
  </div>    
  <div class="cell">
     <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 4 characters long." data-val-length-max="10" data-val-length-min="4" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="" />       
  </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="row">
   <div class="cell">
      <input id="resetButton" type="reset" value="Reset" runat="server"/>
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
       <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The way you use table layout is not correct. Your code actually has only 2 cells and you use `<br/>` to create new lines, that's not the way table layout works.

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhqAX/3/). In this demo, if you notice, you will see that the text `UserName, Password` are also vertically aligned

**Old:**

I wonder why you don't use table tag in this case. You should know that using `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell` has problems with browser compatibility (not all browsers support)

**Update:**
The reason for not using table tag is "semantic web". We choose tags based on their meanings, not by presentation. In this case, table tag is not suitable because table tag is for tabular data, not for layout. Presentation should be Css roles

Comment: I don't use the table tag because table tags are not for layout, they're to tabulate data.

Comment: @Neeta: I forgot about "sematic web". We should choose tags based on `their meanings`, not by presentation.

Comment: `col1` and `col2` don't have meanings.